# Computer readable medium claim rejected by USPTO examiner

Tags: claims, claim-construction

The following claim was rejected by the USPTO examiner for two reasons:

1. For mixing a product and a method.
2. The examiner also stated that the preamble says that this is an independent claim which cannot rely on another claim.

   A computer program product, comprising:
       a non-transitory computer readable medium 
   having stored thereon a computer executable instruction(s) to perform the steps of the method of 
   claim 1.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know an issued US patent or US case law that allows this structure?
2. For me this is clearly a dependent claim so how to convince the examiner about it?

Comment: I think that in the US you cannot claim a computer program product (which is allowed in Europe, but you would not say that the product comprises a computer-readable medium), but instead you should claim a computer-readable medium having instructions thereon. Perhaps somebody with good knowledge of the US patent system can clarify this though.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/computer-readable-medium-claim-rejected-by-uspto-examiner See the answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found two references in issued patents.

```
· U.S. Patent 10,492,242, Wegmann, et al., Claim 20
· U.S. Patent 10,492,208, Petersson, et al., Claim 12
```

Both of these patents claim computer readable medium and include a method of another claim by a reference.

I would say those are Williamson style claims and they are pretty clear when an infringement occurs and they don't mix product and method but rather define a product which has a specific function.

However, USPTO rejects these kinds of claims as they are not constructed in proper dependent form. This is because having stored instruction of a method claim does not equal performing the method claim thus this is not proper dependent form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I do. Check out Claim 10 of [US10067111B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10067111B2/en?oq=14722370)

Which is an independent System claim referring to a method claim

And not only that, but the examiner proposed the amendment. Check out  the response to the 3rd Office Action in the file wrapper. End of **claim 12** -
"a microprocessor programmed to sequence the system to perform continuous measurements within each measurement cycle"

The examiner proposed:
"a microprocessor programmed to sequence the system to perform continuous measurements according to the method of claim 1"

But check out [this blog post](https://www.nutter.com/ip-law-bulletin/when-are-methoddevice-hybrid-claims-indefinite) on case law why method/device hybrid claims may be indefinite.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right link because claim 10 is a dependent method claim? 10. The method of claim 1 further including periodically directing a reference fluid downstream of the sample processing cell and through the separate device to calibrate the separate device.

Comment: It seems to be claim 12 so I edited the answer

Comment: And welcome to Ask Patents Gabriel !

Comment: Guys, I don't see any mention of a computer readable medium neither in claim 10 nor 12 ??? I do see however relevance to another question which I asked in a separate thread so I upvoted your answer but didn't mark it as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, guess I can't count and post in a hurry! Obvious that patent doesn't involve computer readable medium, just an example of a generic 'computer' that can do a claimed method